# How do I change the default login_url in my setting file?

Tags: django

If go to my settings file and try this

login_url = "foo/foobar"

I get page does not exsist. I know I can do this in my view function, but I want to do it from settings file so that I don't need to do for multiple view functions.

Comment: It is `LOGIN_URL` (Uppercase) [Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url)

Comment: it still takes me to 'accounts/login' page and gives me no page exists. I want it to take it foo/login page instead.

Comment: do you have foo/login in your urls?

Comment: yeah I do. But as I said, it tames me to accounts/login page- This is the default one according to the documentation.

Comment: LOGIN_URL = '/foo/foobar/' This must work. If not, that means you have a bug somewhere else in the code.